# Gitclone and git push on Github

Tags: git, github, repository, push, clone

Good afternoon,
I have done a git clone of one of my repositories on my machine. Then I created an empty git repository on GitHub. But I did not manage then to push my files.

I wanted to push my files to GitHub using the following commands:

- git init
- git@github.com:myname/myrepositoryname.git
- git branch -M main
- git push origin main
  I received this error error: src refspec git@github.com does not match any
  error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:LaureCDev/idealplace.git'.
  I have tried once before, that time it seemed to work but there was nothing in my GitHub repository...
  What do I do wrong please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `git@github.com:myname/myrepositoryname.git` this is not a valid complete command.  You really must represent the commands you ran exactly and specifically for us to help you.  Best to copy-paste the text of the command *and* its output (*not* a screenshot) because the response to these commands is often relevant for debugging

Answer (score 1):

`git@github.com:myname/myrepositoryname.git`
it is not a command its remote URL in SSH format

- If you're setting up a new repository or need to change the remote URL, you can use:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myname/myrepositoryname.git
```

This command adds a remote named "origin" with the specified SSH URL